# Is there way to copy the local docker image to Minikube docker environment?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, continuous-integration, devops, minikube

Currently i created a docker image by using build command in the minikube itself. But i need to know is there any way to copy the docker image in my system docker daemon to minikube docker daemon environment. I don't need to use Dockerhub.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can point your terminal to use the docker daemon inside minikube by running this,

```sh
$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Then you can build your own image,

```sh
docker build -t my_image .
```

For more info, see https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/

Comment: Currently i was using this method. What i need is i have a docker image but it is in my system docker daemon. I need to move this image to minikube docker daemon.

Comment: @I.vigneshDavid You can save the docker image in your system using [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/), and then [docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) from minikube env.